# Tags: How should we handle census-related tags?

Tags: discussion

We currently have tags: [us-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) [uk-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-census) [united-states](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [uk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk), as well as [census-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census-records) and [1940-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1940-census).

Could we get by with a set of tags for e.g. census-records, geographical units, and decades? Or is there value in very census-related granular tags?

Comment: The tag wiki's for these tags need to be filled out. As of this writing, not one of the tags mentioned has any text.

Comment: @duncan, it was my intention to do some of them, once this issue is sorted. Feel free to beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

Remove [us-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) and [uk-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-census). It is better to use [united-states](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [uk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) in combination with [census-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census-records) because questions regarding those topics will be easier to find.

If I wanted to browse question regarding [united-states](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), or subscribe to receive email alerts when new [united-states](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) questions are asked, I would not see [us-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) questions unless they were also tagged [united-states](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). But I also want to see them if I subscribe to [census-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census-records), so I add that one too, and now [us-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) becomes totally redundant.

Also, I can't imagine any valid question that would apply to [us-census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) but nothing else, especially since the only thing they have in common is being taken at the start of a decade in the US.

Comment: Why do we have "united-states" but then have "uk"? Should the former be "us" or "usa" or the latter be "united-kingdom"?

Comment: I think we should turn "uk" into "united-kingdom", but we should probably turn that into separate meta question so that others can share their opinion.

Comment: @JustinY, I'd rather change united-states to usa and retain uk -- shorter is better IMO for tags. But I'll wait for the new meta question...

Answer (score 0):

Clearly we can do more with astute combinations of general purpose tags (with greater efficiency) than can be achieved with a multitude of stand-alone tags.

HOWEVER, that is not the principle that has been followed to date. New tags have been created that are slight variants of those already in use. Should the community adopt the eminently sensible idea of "fewer is better", someone (a dedicated moderator?) has got a lot of weeding to do.

Note also that if we have {census} + {usa}, do we also need {1940}? How do we deal with the fact that different countries conduct their census on different cycles? And if we use {census} + {ny} + {1915}, should {usa} be appended even though it is not a federal census?

Comment: I've gone with [tag:census] and [tag:united-states] plus a tag for the relevant decade. But before anybody tidies tidies up, the community needs to reach a consensus on what to do.

Comment: If I was dealing with a local census I'd probably use [tag:census] plus a tag for the locality and the decade. [tag:usa] might be needed to refine the locality (think Birmingham for example).